# converting datatype from float to unicode and suppress decimal

Tags: python, string, pandas, unicode, floating-point

I need to import the entire dataframe as string. The way I do this is via:

> df = read_csv('filename')
>
> df = df.astype('unicode')

The problem with this is that the columns detected as float objects are converted to have values with decimals '.0'. Eg:

Original value:

`2014` while the value in dataframe is `2014.0`

My current solution involves importing the dataframe as:

> df = read_csv('filename', dtype='unicode')
>
> df = df.astype('unicode')

Converting the dataframe again takes a bit more time. I was wondering if there a better way?

Comment: Sounds like your issue is that `integer` values are being converted to `float`? If so, this usually happens because the column has missing values. If this is the case, and you really want `integer` dtype then you could use `.fillna()` with an `integer` that indicates missing values, like `-1`.

Comment: If you have missing values then the `dtype` will be `float` can you try passing `dtype=str` as a param to `read_csv`

Comment: Try to include some sample data and your actual and desired output, tghis might make things clearer.